# react-router-dom NavLink Icon Updater "Maximum update depth exceeded."

Tags: javascript, reactjs

We are working on a project using React.js. I am configuring multiple pages utilizing react-router-dom, and I want to change the currently active icon using NavLink.

icon+sel is for active page.

I have rewritten the code based on the answers to previous questions. SetState also came out of render, and I touched other settings a little bit.

error.... [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHn32.png)

console...
[console-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bF20J.png)       [console-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZjBq.png)

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link, NavLink, Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import home from './home.svg';
import homesel from './homesel.svg';
import search from './search.svg';
import searchsel from './searchsel.svg';
import setting from './setting.svg';
import settingsel from './settingsel.svg';
import add from './add.svg';
import addsel from './addsel.svg';
import account from './account.svg';
import accountsel from './accountsel.svg';


import './Bottom.css';



class Bottom extends React.Component {
  state = {
    iconName : 'initialIconName'
  }

  setIconName = (name) => {
    this.setState(() => ({
      iconName: name
    }))
  }

  oddEvent = (match, location) => {
  if (!match) return false
  console.log(location.pathname.substr(1).split('/')[0])
  this.setState(() => ({
    iconName: location.pathname.substr(1).split('/')[0]
  }))
  }

    render() {
      return (
          <fragment>
            <div className="bottom noright">
              <div className="bottomcontents">
                <div className="bottomicon">
                    <NavLink className="bottomiconinside bottomiconinsideside" src={home} exact to="/" isActive={this.oddEvent}>
                    <img className="iconcenter" src={require(`./home${this.state.iconName == 'home' ? 'sel' : ''}.svg`)}/>
                    </NavLink>
                    <NavLink className="bottomiconinside bottomiconinsideside" exact to="/search" isActive={this.oddEvent}>
                    <img className="iconcenter" src={require(`./search${this.state.iconName == 'search' ? 'sel' : ''}.svg`)}/>
                    </NavLink>
                    <NavLink className="bottomiconinside bottomiconinsideside" to="/add" isActive={this.oddEvent} >
                    <img className="iconcenter" src={require(`./add${this.state.iconName == 'add' ? 'sel' : ''}.svg`)}/>
                    </NavLink>
                    <NavLink className="bottomiconinside bottomiconinsideside" to="/account" isActive={this.oddEvent}>
                    <img className="iconcenter" src={require(`./account${this.state.iconName == 'account' ? 'sel' : ''}.svg`)}/>
                    </NavLink>
                    <NavLink className="bottomiconinside bottomiconinsideside" exact to="/setting" isActive={this.oddEvent}>
                    <img className="iconcenter" src={require(`./setting${this.state.iconName == 'setting' ? 'sel' : ''}.svg`)}/>
                    </NavLink>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
              </fragment>
        );
    }

  }

export default Bottom;
```

Comment: Can you share the console output as well please?

Comment: Added! The address I accessed was localhost:3000/search.

Comment: I also added an error screenshot!

Comment: Try to avoid calling setState() from inside oddEvent

Comment: However, I should use oddEvent. I think we can check the active page with oddEvent and change the icon ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling setState() from inside oddEvent (the screenshot shows it). You cannot do that from render(), which causes a re-render, which calls oddEvent, which calls setState(), which causes a re-render, and on and on and on.

You will have to re-think your design.